# How can add UIImageView in RTLabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uilabel

I'm creating an iOS article reading application for iPhone which contain multiple headings, images and multiline text.

I am using `RTLabel` to parse html data, the html contains images. I'll create the images from url and add imageview in the RTlabel, but images are not displayed in teh `RTlabel`.

Where is what I have so far:

```
   label = [[RTLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 270, 300, 1000)];
   [self.scroller addSubview:label];
    NSString *aString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:_DetailModal1[3] ];
    NSString *newS=[aString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp;" withString:@""];
    NSString *newString=  [newS stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br\/>" withString:@"<br>"];
   NSRange rangeOfString = NSMakeRange(0, [newString length]);
          NSString *pattern = @"src=\"([^\"]+)\"";
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray *matchs = [regex matchesInString:newString options:0 range:rangeOfString];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matchs) {
        NSLog(@"url: %@", [newString  substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
        NSString *imageUrl=[newString  substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
        NSRange range = [newString rangeOfString:imageUrl];
        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromRange(range));
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            UIImageView*    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
            [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, range.location, 320, 160)];
        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: imageUrl]];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

            imgView.image=image;
            [label addSubview:imgView];  //adding imageview in the RTlabel

            }
        else {
            NSLog(@"not found");

        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(RTLabel)Rich text formatting based on HTML-like markups for iOS.
```

it's not for showing parsed image too, you have to try something more manual formatting for your purpose

Comment: hii Retro,I added image view in RTLabel and it's not display the images. [label addSubview:imgView];  //adding imageview in the RTlabel
I created the images by getting its url.